# IE adds extra padding around image

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having problems with IE adding extra padding to an image. I searched the forums, but didn't find a solution for my problem.

The first image shows how it is in all other browsers (as it should be), and the second one - what IE shows.

The image is in a table cell with the following code:

```
<td width="372" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="border:1px solid #ADE1EF; padding: 5px;">
<img id="image1" src="http://siteaddress.com/image.JPG" style="width:368px; height:370px;" />
</td>
```

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please add a fiddle or somelike

Comment: What version IE are you using. And show some more code. It could be that your markup is invalid. IE is very strict about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about your table cell formatting.  In IE, the table cells are touching each other with no space between them.  In other browsers, they are not touching and have spacing between them.  I haven't looked into why IE is doing it differently, but the place for you to look is in how your table cell width and margins are specified, nothing to do with your images.

Comment: I tested it in IE 9 , 10 and 11 Dev Preview. The three of them shows it the same way.
I tried the font-size trick but it doesn't work. The code I posted above is in one line.

Comment: @DJAntie - Well, if you want anything other than wild guesses, post a link to a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem with a working image link.  Another wild guess is that IE has a default left/right padding or margin on  images which you can override with CSS.

Comment: This is the page: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/290954454845?var=&ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1558.l2649

The same problem is in gallery view: http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Kids-Chic-Shop/_i.html?_fsub=9271186018

Comment: @DJAntie - the first link looks the same to me in IE10 and Chrome 28.  I see no difference.

Comment: @DJAntie - the second page looks like table formatting differences to me, nothing to do with the image.

Comment: do the borders of the three cells in the second link touch each other in IE for you?

Comment: @DJAntie - yes they touch, that's why it's a table cell formatting issue.